# Задача взаимного исключения

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Рассмотрите следующее решение задачи взаимного исключения, затрагивающей два процесса, **P0** и **P1**. Предположим, что переменная `turn` имеет исходное значение 0. Код процесса **P0** на картинке:

[image: код]

По логике, нужно выйти из блока `while (turn != 0)`, но как это сделать не понимаю.

Comment: Рассмотрите решение, это значит, что перед вами некое решение задачи и его надо рассмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже тут рассматривается некая упрощенная специфическая разновидность [алгоритма Петерсона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) для реализации критической секции.

Похоже, что есть два процесса `P0` и `P1`.

P0:

```
while (turn != 0) { }
// критическая секция
turn = 0;
```

P1:

```
while (turn != 1) { }
// критическая секция
turn = 1;
```

Переменная `turn` используется для передачи сигнала о том, что процесс вышел из критической секции. А значит второй процесс может продолжать выполнение и следовательно зайти в критическую секцию. Каждый процесс ждет, пока не наступит его очередь. А его очередь наступает, когда другой процесс разрешит. Т.е. `P0` сможет выйти из цикла, когда процесс `P1` закончит выполнение критической секции и установит `turn=1`.